# React unit test on .NET project. how to?

Tags: reactjs, .net, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I need to unit test `React` components (tsx) that are part of a `.NET` project.

I have tried using `react-testing-library` and `ts-jest`, but it was useless without all the `.NET` project running.

Is it possible to make jest run the project, or make jest "ride" somehow on the project when it is running?

alternatively, is there another way to test it?

Thank you.